# Copy content from one file to another but no duplicates bash/python

Tags: python, bash

My file1 looks like this:

```
############# IMPORTANT ################
########################################

# more comments
# more comments 2

# values 1
#######################
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_1=10 # comments
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_2=40 # comments

# values 2
######################
export SIMPLE_RULE=222
export IMPORTANT_RUN_COMMAND=190

# values 3
#################
export COMMAND_EXEC=3
export NUMBER_STORED=3
```

My file2 looks like this:

```
############# IMPORTANT ################
########################################

# more comments
# more comments 2

# values 1
#######################
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_1=5 # comments
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_2=8 # comments
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_3=2 # comments
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_4=2 # comments

# values 2
######################
export SIMPLE_RULE=45
export IMPORTANT_RUN_COMMAND=2
export COMMANDER=45

# values 3
#################
export COMMAND_EXEC=2
export NUMBER_STORED=5
export RUN_ONLY_ONCE=0

# values 4
##############
export NEW_VALUE=5
```

What I'd like is to copy just the variables that doesn't exists on the file 1 but not changing the values if values from file2 are different than values from file1

So the final file I'd like to look like:

```
############# IMPORTANT ################
########################################

# more comments
# more comments 2

# values 1
#######################
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_1=10 # comments
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_2=40 # comments
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_3=2 # comments
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_4=2 # comments

# values 2
######################
export SIMPLE_RULE=222
export IMPORTANT_RUN_COMMAND=190
export COMMANDER=45

# values 3
#################
export COMMAND_EXEC=3
export NUMBER_STORED=3
export RUN_ONLY_ONCE=0

# values 4
##############
export NEW_VALUE=5
```

Is it there a way to do this in bash or python [preferable bash]?

Comment: Do you want the rest of the file to be the same as well (structurally) or you just want the variables to be copied over?

Comment: If possible to have the structure same it will be easier to read the file on multiple machines, but if that's not possible then just having the variables will be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a bash script created by myself.

```
# Define files locations
file1Name="file1"
file2Name="file2"

# Set current date for backup hours-minutes-seconds_month-day-year
currentDate=$(date +"%H-%M-%S_%m-%d-%Y")

# Create backup of the original file
backupLocationFile="file1_${currentDate}"
cp ${file1Name} ${backupLocationFile}

# Overwrite existing file with the new one
cp ${file2Name} ${file1Name}

while read -r line; do
    # If line is not a statement like variableName=variableValue or it is a comment, or it is empty - continue
    if [[ "$line" == "#"* || "$line" != *"="* || -z "$line" ]]; then
        continue
    fi

    # Get variable name/value from line
    variableName=$(echo $line | cut -d '=' -f 1 | sed -s 's/export//g' | awk '{print $1}')
    variableValue=$(echo $line | cut -d '=' -f 2 | awk '{print $1}')

    # If variable name exists on the existing file, adjust values accordingly
    if grep -q "$variableName" ${file1Name}; then
        if [[ "$line" == *"#"* ]]; then
            # Keep old value but if there are comments after the value keep it as well
            sed -i "s/.*${variableName}.*#/export ${variableName}=${variableValue} #/g" ${file1Name}
        else
            # Keep old value
            sed -i "s/.*${variableName}.*/export ${variableName}=${variableValue}/g" ${file1Name}
        fi
    else
        # If there are custom values added by the client manually we should save them and add again to the file at the bottom of it
        echo "$line" >> /tmp/custom_values
    fi
done < ${backupLocationFile}

# If file is not empty [custom_values], add values at the end of the existing file
if [ -s "/tmp/custom_values" ]; then
    echo -e "\n\n" >> ${file1Name}
    echo "#################################" >> ${file1Name}
    echo "# Values added manually by client" >> ${file1Name}
    echo "#################################" >> ${file1Name}
    cat ${file1Name} /tmp/custom_values > /tmp/file2

    # Move created file to the file1Name
    mv /tmp/file2 ${file1Name}

    # cleanup
    rm -rf /tmp/custom_values
fi
```

This one will keep the order of variables names as well as it will keep comments if any

Answer (score 1):

This simple script will merge the files, but it won't keep the comments nor the variables order. This is an example of the output:

```
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_1=10 
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_2=40 
export SIMPLE_RULE=222
export IMPORTANT_RUN_COMMAND=190
export COMMAND_EXEC=3
export NUMBER_STORED=3
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_3=2 
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_4=2 
export COMMANDER=45
export RUN_ONLY_ONCE=0
export NEW_VALUE=5
```

Script:

```py
def get_file_values(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        f_lines = f.readlines()
    # Remove comments and empty lines
    values = filter(lambda el: not el.startswith("#") and el.strip(), f_lines)
    # Keep only vars values
    key_value_list = map(lambda el: el.strip().split("#")[0].replace("export ", "").split("="), values)
    # Return vars dict
    return {k: v for k, v in key_value_list}


# Load files
file_1_vars = get_file_values("file1")
file_2_vars = get_file_values("file2")
# Check vars
keys_1 = file_1_vars.keys()
for key, value in file_2_vars.items():
    if key not in keys_1:
        file_1_vars[key] = value

# Write output
with open("file3", "w") as out:
    out.write("\n".join(f"export {key}={value}" for key, value in file_1_vars.items()))
```

**EDIT: Keep variable order and block division**

The code look a bit messy, but it does the job, look at its output.

```py
def get_file_values(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        f_lines = f.readlines()

    max_f_lines = len(f_lines)
    i = 0
    var_blocks = {}
    while i < max_f_lines - 2:
        # Check if next occurrences contains a variables block
        if f_lines[i].startswith("# ") and f_lines[i + 1].startswith("##") and f_lines[i + 2].startswith("export"):
            block = f_lines[i][2:].strip()
            var_blocks[block] = {}
            i += 2
            # Add variables to block
            while i < max_f_lines and f_lines[i].startswith("export"):
                # Remove \n and comment. Then remove export and split var name and value
                key_value = f_lines[i].strip().split("#")[0].replace("export ", "").split("=")
                # Remove any whitespace if still present
                key = key_value[0].strip()
                value = key_value[1].strip()
                # Populate var_blocks
                var_blocks[block][key] = value
                i += 1
        else:
            i += 1
    # At this point we return a dictionary divided per block like:
    # {'values 1': {'VALUE_IMPORTANT_1': '10', 'VALUE_IMPORTANT_2': '40'},
    #  'values 2': {'SIMPLE_RULE': '222', 'IMPORTANT_RUN_COMMAND': '190'},
    #  'values 3': {'COMMAND_EXEC': '3', 'NUMBER_STORED': '3'}}
    return var_blocks


# Load files variables
file_1_vars = get_file_values("file1")
file_2_vars = get_file_values("file2")
# Get keys
keys_1 = file_1_vars.keys()
keys_2 = file_2_vars.keys()
# Initialize new file vars and start merge
new_file_vars = {}
for key in keys_1:
    new_file_vars[key] = {}
    for k, v in file_1_vars[key].items():
        new_file_vars[key][k] = v

    # Check if key is also in file2
    if key in file_2_vars:
        already_added_keys = new_file_vars[key].keys()
        for k, v in file_2_vars[key].items():
            # Add the value only if it isn't already present in file1
            if k not in already_added_keys:  
                new_file_vars[key][k] = v

# Finally, add all keys that are present in the second file but not in the first
for key in keys_2:
    if key not in keys_1:
        new_file_vars[key] = {}
        for k, v in file_2_vars[key].items():
            new_file_vars[key][k] = v

# Write output
with open("file3", "w") as out:
    out.write("############# IMPORTANT ################\n"
              "########################################\n\n")
    for key in new_file_vars.keys():
        out.write(f"# {key}\n{'#' * 40}\n")
        for k, v in new_file_vars[key].items():
            out.write(f"export {k}={v}\n")

        out.write("\n")  # Leave a blank line after a block
```

Output file:

```
############# IMPORTANT ################
########################################

# values 1
########################################
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_1=10
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_2=40
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_3=2
export VALUE_IMPORTANT_4=2

# values 2
########################################
export SIMPLE_RULE=222
export IMPORTANT_RUN_COMMAND=190
export COMMANDER=45

# values 3
########################################
export COMMAND_EXEC=3
export NUMBER_STORED=3
export RUN_ONLY_ONCE=0

# values 4
########################################
export NEW_VALUE=5
```

Comment: Is it there a way to keep at least the variables order. Asking as if I want to have e.g. export RUN_ONLY_ONCE=$VALUE_IMPORTANT_1 it may not work if VALUE_IMPORTANT_1 is defined after RUN_ONLY_ONCE

Comment: I've just updated the answer. It ain't much and it's a little messy but it does the job

Comment: unfortunately only the first script is doing what it should [more or less because will mess with the order] the second one will not do the job

Comment: That's weird. I've tested both script with the two input files and they both works. The only flaw of the second script is that it expect variables' blocks like the ones you declared in the test script